# How to search usertimeline in twitter

Tags: twitter

I am able to display home timeline in my site.However there is one more functionality in my site where we can search Home timeline of a user.I know that there is a search by which i can get tweets related to a keyword.But i want to get results for a specific home timeline only.
Any pointers to that
Many thanks

SMith

Comment: Twitter have not yet released an API which allows you to see all the tweets a user sees. The nearest you can do is to put all their friends into a list and then look at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [twitter.com/search](http://twitter.com/search) for searching tweets, use "from:USERNAME" as Keyword in searchform for get tweets by user.

Look at all opeartors on the page, linked above.

Is that what you search?

Comment: I guess that would only give tweets by the user.However i want to search any of the tweets in the user timeline ..that means all the tweets that show on the homepage of user.These include the tweets by the user whom he is following. Thanks